# Multi arguments query in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table in sqlite that contains 4 columns(id,group,description,status).
I can make query On this table when my where clause is just ONE field, like this:

```
public Question readQuestion(long _id) {String[] columns = new String[]{"id", "group", "description", "status"};
    String selection = "id=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(_id)};
    String groupBy = null;
    String having = null;
    String orderBy = null;
    String limit = null;
    database = sqLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query("my_table", columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
    .......etc.....
}
```

but my PROBLEM is when I have to make query on 2 or 3 columns and also one or two of them may be NULL. for example when my GROUP field serch with (A,B,or null) and STATUS search with (1,2,or null). I think it is in 'selection' and 'selectionArgs' but I don't know how can figure it.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
String selection = "( id=? || id=? || id=? ) && ( status =? || status=? || status=? )";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"1","2",null,"A","B",null};
```

Or

```
String selection = "id IN ( ?,?,? ) && status IN (? ,? ,? )";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"1","2",null,"A","B",null};
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, it works But I have 2 more issue,

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, it works But I have 2 more issue, 1: Is there any way that I pass null in selectionArgs and query doesn't look for that field? I've done it on sql server like in stored procedure : /@status int=NULL and in sql syntax I pass it like:((/@status is null) OR (status = /@status )) .?and 2:Number of values of each selection in where clause is variable, some times is 1, sometimes is 2 ,sometimes is 3 etc, how can figure it in selection? i can parse the inputs depend the length and make a String but is there a better and dynamic way? thanks a lot.

Comment: 1 :you should pass null while storing values if no values, 2: you shoud write for logic in generation of the "select"